# Disk full, table crash... what is the right way to repair without phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, repair

The mysql database files is in a partition. mysql suddenly unavailable because partition full 100%

so I remove other files and start mysql.

everything fine but when browse my website, there is a message telling me that table `./k1/cache_filter` is marked as crashed:

```
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache_filter WHERE cid = '3:5798c3c8b649979ac97799d5bbf9fbc5' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 26.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: UPDATE cache_filter SET data = '<form name=\"form1\">\n<select style=\"font-size:12px;color:#8BAB6B;font-family:verdana;background-color:#ffffff;\" name=\"menu\">\n<option value=\"#\">----Submit----</option>\n<option value=\"http://www.mysite.com/node/add/komputer\">Trik</option>\n<option value=\"http://www.mysite.com/node/add/forum\">Forum</option>\n<option value=\"http://www.mysite.com/node/add/freebies\">Freebies</option>\n</select>\n<input style=\"font-size:12px;color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana;background-color:#A7CE80;\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"location=document.form1.menu.options[document.form1.menu.selectedIndex].value;\" value=\"Go\">\n</form>\n\n<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/user\">&#8226; Login | Register &#8226;<br>&#8226; My Account &#8226;</a></div>', created = 1293070347, expire = 1293156747, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid = '3:5798c3c8b649979ac97799d5bbf9fbc5' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 109.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache_filter WHERE cid = '3:211aa9fdb9976e821c3a565826a36d16' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 26.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: UPDATE cache_filter SET data = '<p align=\"center\"><script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--\ngoogle_ad_client = \"pub-8495709850146104\";\n/* eyecandy2u 160x600, created 7/10/09 */\ngoogle_ad_slot = \"1295348390\";\ngoogle_ad_width = 160;\ngoogle_ad_height = 600;\n//-->\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\"\nsrc=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\">\n</script></p>', created = 1293070347, expire = 1293156747, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid = '3:211aa9fdb9976e821c3a565826a36d16' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 109.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache_filter WHERE cid = '3:a347380abe409e26d216f14e039e66d2' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 26.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: UPDATE cache_filter SET data = '<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/artikel/all\"><img src=\"http://img.nattawat.org/images/1wdfaq3zl5cf7czjprb9.png\"></a>', created = 1293070347, expire = 1293156747, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid = '3:a347380abe409e26d216f14e039e66d2' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 109.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache_filter WHERE cid = '3:5636feaceb0a27ee732eaf45616989c8' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 26.
* user warning: Table './k1/cache_filter' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: UPDATE cache_filter SET data = '<!-- BEGIN STANDARD TAG - 728 x 90 - ROS: Run-of-site - DO NOT MODIFY -->\n<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=728 HEIGHT=90 SRC=\"http://ad.globe7.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=417236\"></IFRAME>\n<!-- END TAG -->', created = 1293070347, expire = 1293156747, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid = '3:5636feaceb0a27ee732eaf45616989c8' in /home/www/html/www.mysite.com/includes/cache.inc on line 109.
```

This is drupal website. Previuosly I'm using phpmyadmin.

But now, I trying to live without phpmyadmin

so, what is the right way to repair without phpmyadmin

Comment: Not the answer you want - but do you have a backup that you can restore?

Comment: yes i have.. but the backup is out dated (last week)

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at `REPAIR TABLE cache_filter`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: `ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected` (I have many drupal database in the server)

Comment: `USE DATABASE k1` - assuming your database name is k1